# MAAS node status deployed - but unknown error

Tags: maas, cluster

I'm trying to install and make MAAS function on a cluster of machine used for distributed/parallel computation purpose at a university lab. The node statuses read 'deployed'. But for some reason, they still have 'orange' dots before the FQDNs - which shows up 'unknown' when hovered over. The latest node events read as follows:

```
Level  Emitted Event
INFO    Thu, 06 Aug. 2015 10:11:04  Node changed status — From 'Deploying' to 'Deployed'
INFO    Thu, 06 Aug. 2015 10:10:39  PXE Request — local boot
INFO    Thu, 06 Aug. 2015 10:09:47  Installation complete — Node disabled netboot
INFO    Thu, 06 Aug. 2015 10:06:34  PXE Request — curtin install
```

Why doesn't the dot have green colour. What could be wrong?

Nodes tab in MAAS:

[image]